# Homomorphic Encryption with Addition and Exponentiation

Tags: algorithm-design, homomorphic-encryption

Is there any homomorphic encryption scheme which supports addition and power over cipher text ? Paillier is close but it supports addition and multiplication with a constant.

I am getting an output like this:

```
1 0 1 0 -1 1
```

My goal is to make -1 positive by any means. As it will encrypted so I cannot know if it is -1 or 1. This (similar) output is being generated by subtracting binary streams.

For example:

```
101101 -- A1
111001 --- A2
----------------------------
2 1 2 1 1 0 2 --- A+A2=A3
----------------------------
1 0 1 0 -1 1 ---- A3-1
```

A1 and A2 bits can be replaced to any other integers.
Also, can I perform AND operation in additive mode ?
Please note that this question is link to my previous [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30249/making-pascal-paillier-output-absolute)

**Primary Objective:**
To be able to check any of following

1. How many same bits occurs that is 1ns in A1 and A2 in the same position
2. How many zero bits on the same positions in A1 and A2
3. How many different bit locations in A1 and A2

Comment: Is the plaintext space limited to ```-1,0,1```?

Comment: plain text space is not limited to any value. To achieve my result i can use any values.

Comment: If it were limited to ```-1,0,1``` I could see where squaring the ciphertext would ensure that $-1\to 1$. If it is not limited, as you say, how does exponentiation help you achieve your goal of making the value positive?

Comment: by taking square of each bit result.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you, as it seems like you aren't getting anywhere with your questions. You have some problem you are trying to solve and you have some direction on a solution (i.e., use homomorphic encryption). You are asking us about a problem with the possible solution, and that is going nowhere. I suggest you better explain the problem you are trying to solve. That context would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you really mean to "check **any** of the following" or do you mean "to check **all** of the following"?

Comment: I have added more detail in the question. And it is **Any** of the following. The fact is if you can find any of it then you will be able to find all.

Comment: [BGN cryptosystem](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs259c/lectures/bgn.pdf) can perform any number of additions and one single multiplication. That may help.

Comment: so you mean i first calculate: A1[i]*A2[i] and then calculate A1[i]+A2[i] ? if this is the case, is not multiplication being performed multiple times ?

Comment: I was more thinking about the case of subtraction. Subtract two bits, the result will be either 1, 0, or -1. Then multiply by itself. Now the result is either 1 or 0.

Comment: Agreed but would it not be considered as more than one multiplications ?

Comment: Why, you are adding two things together, then doing one multiplication?

Comment: Hmm. I will try it. Is there opensource implementation available for BGN ?

Comment: Check with the poster of [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/if-you-had-to-implement-the-bgn-cryptosystem-how-would-you-do-it). I am not aware of any. There is also an [LWE variant](https://people.csail.mit.edu/vinodv/lwe-bgn.pdf).

Comment: yet I am not sure will it work or not but in my mind multiplying each bit itself is causing N number of multiplications if there are N bits but still I will give it a hit.

Comment: I don't understand well what is your problem... Are you working in a bit level and do you just want to eliminate those minus ones? If yes, you can just encrypt each bit, getting a vector and do operations component-wise and at the end multiply each component by itself.
But if you are really needing a scheme that permits you to add and power ciphertexts, I think the schemes based on LWE or RLWE are the better for you...

Comment: Your question seems essentially the same that [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32830/is-there-an-additive-homomorphic-encryption-that-supports-exponentation?lq=1), you might want to check the answer I gave here, as it provides several alternatives.
Also, is it absolutely necessary for you that the scheme directly support those operations, or could they be performed interactively, between two or more players? If so, there are two-party and multiparty protocols for computing Enc(abs(m)) from Enc(m) without disclosing m.

Answer (score 2):

(In most generality..) you're looking for fully homomorphic encryption (FHE), which supports homomorphic addition and homomorphic multiplication. To compute a plaintext's exponentiation, you would run the repeating squaring algorithm (using homomorphic multiplication), to generate an (evaluated) homomorphic ciphertext containing the input-plaintext's exponentiation.

Craig Gentry gave the breakthrough construction of FHE in 2009. Since then, there's been a titanic volume of work improving the techniques, and multiple surveys are available by searching online.

An open-source implementation of modern FHE -- the library HElib by Shai Halevi and Victor Shoup -- can be found here: https://github.com/shaih/HElib

Comment: As of practicality of the leading edge two years ago, the introduction of Shai Halevi and Victor Shoup's [_Bootstrapping for HElib_](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/873.pdf#page=3) is very telling.

Answer (score 0):

[This scheme](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~eujin/papers/2dnf/2dnf.pdf) is additively homomorphic and supports one multiplication. So if you multiply the ciphertext with itself you can get a square. I don't know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any opensource implementation available for this scheme ?